# android using json and rest

Tags: android, json, rest

I am just beginning to look at using json and a rest client setup to connect with a rest server.  Is there a server that can be accessed just so I can try my code and see what is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blizzard just opened up their API for JSON using HTTP. So it's probably really close to what you're looking for, and it's got potentially LOT of interesting data to play with, even if you don't play the game.

http://blizzard.github.com/api-wow-docs/

Note, you may be limited how much you can use it. But for a simple app and testing, this should not be a problem.